# Risk-free interval in Andersen-Gill counting process formulation for Cox regression using survival::tmerge()

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I would like to use the `tmerge()` function to transform the dataset for use in the Andersen-Gill extension of the Cox regression framework for repeated events. See Therneau's [excellent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf).

I would like to specify that the individual is immune to a repeated event for 30 days after an event, i.e. I would like the individual to exit the risk set temporarily, such that if an event occurs when the individual is not at-risk, it is ignored.

A primitive approach would be to add all the events iteratively and then simply add 30 to `tstart` variable. However, this could cause instances were `tstart >= tstop`, and would be catastrophic in larger and more complex datasets.

I have attempted to exploit the `tmerge()` function with a forloop correcting for the problems I mention above. For this example I will be using the `cgd` data in the survival package.

**EDIT: See corrected forloop below**

```
library(survival)
cgd0 <- cgd0
newcgd <- tmerge(data1=cgd0[, 1:13], data2=cgd0, id=id, tstop=futime)

for(i in 1:7){        
    x <- paste0("etime", i)  #etime1:etime7

# iteratively add each event
    newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))

# select only observations that end in an event and iteratively create
# cumulative number of events for each individual
    newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1),
                     id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))

# for each loop add 30 days to the start time of the ith cumulative event
    newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] <-
           newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] + 30

# for each loop remove observations were the start time >= stop time
    newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]
}

attr(newcgd, "tcount")
#            early late gap within boundary leading trailing tied
#infect         0    0   0     44        0       0        0    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0       44       0        0    0
#infect         0    0   4     11        0       1        1    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0       11       0       45    0
#infect         0    0   2      6        0       0        0    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0        6       0       56    0
#infect         0    0   1      2        0       0        0    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0        6       0       58    0
#infect         0    0   0      2        0       0        0    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0        8       0       58    0
#infect         0    0   0      1        0       0        0    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0        9       0       58    0
#infect         0    0   0      1        0       0        0    0
#cum_infect     0    0   0      0       10       0       58    0
```

I believe this solution to be correct. However, this is a common problem in survival analysis and I am concerned that

i) I am overlooking something and the code does not do what I think it does.

ii) I am overlooking a validated way to do this in R

iii) If i) and ii) are not issues, I believe this code to be inefficient and wonder whether there are obvious ways to improve the speed of execution.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

EDIT: Further error-checking with comments. Hopefully this clarifies a bit what I am attempting to do. Conceptually; I am specifying that an individual is not at-risk of having another event for 30 days after experiencing an event. In the Andersen-Gill counting process formulation, each line represents an observation that contains a start-time `tstart`and a stop-time `tstop` and an indicator (in this case `infect`) which indicates whether the observation ended due to the event `infect == 1` or censoring `infect == 0`. Here I manually go through the steps in the forloop above and quantify for each loop how many events take place and the total follow-up time when a 30 day immune period is either specified or not. This same code is then implemented as a forloop for completeness. The results are shown below in a separate code chunk.

```
newcgd <- tmerge(data1=cgd0[, 1:13], data2=cgd0, id=id, tstop=futime)

###1st event

x <- "etime1"
immunecgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 1), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 1), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 1), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 1), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime1 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime1 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

###2nd event
x <- "etime2"
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 2), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 2), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 2), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 2), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime2 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime2 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

###3rd event
x <- "etime3"
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 3), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 3), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 3), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 3), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime3 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime3 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

###4th event
x <- "etime4"
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 4), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 4), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 4), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 4), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime4 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime4 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

###5th event
x <- "etime5"
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 5), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 5), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 5), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 5), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime5 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime5 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

###6th event
x <- "etime6"
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 6), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 6), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 6), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 6), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime6 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime6 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

###7th event
x <- "etime7"
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 7), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == 7), "tstart"] + 30
immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]

newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 7), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == 7), "tstart"]
newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

etime7 <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
futime7 <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))

df_event <- rbind.data.frame(etime1, etime2, etime3, etime4, etime5, etime6, etime7)
colnames(df_event) <- c("immunity", "no_immunity")
df_event$diff <- df_event$no_immunity - df_event$immunity

df_futime <- rbind.data.frame(futime1, futime2, futime3, futime4, futime5, futime6, futime7)
colnames(df_futime)  <- c("immunity", "no_immunity")
df_futime$diff <- df_futime$no_immunity - df_futime$immunity
```

The same code as a forloop.

```
 newcgd <- tmerge(data1=cgd0[, 1:13], data2=cgd0, id=id, tstop=futime)
 immunecgd <- tmerge(data1=cgd0[, 1:13], data2=cgd0, id=id, tstop=futime)

event <- matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol = 2)
futime <- matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol = 2)
for(i in 1:7){        
    x <- paste0("etime", i)  #etime1:etime7

    # iteratively add each event
    immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
    newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))

    # select only observations that end in an event and iteratively create
    # cumulative number of events for each individual
    immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
    newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))

    # for each loop add 30 days to the start time of the ith cumulative event
    immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] + 30
    newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] <- newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"]

    # for each loop remove observations were the start time >= stop time
    immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]
    newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

    event[i,] <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
    futime[i,] <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))
}

event <- data.frame(event)
colnames(event) <- c("immunity", "no_immunity")
event$diff <- event$no_immunity - event$immunity

futime <- data.frame(futime)
colnames(futime) <- c("immunity", "no_immunity")
futime$diff <- futime$no_immunity - futime$immunity
```

The error-testing code above gives the following results

```
df_event
  immunity no_immunity diff
1       44          44    0
2       56          61    5
3       62          69    7
4       64          72    8
5       66          74    8
6       67          75    8
7       68          76    8

df_futime
  immunity no_immunity diff
1    36202       37477 1275
2    35935       37477 1542
3    35875       37477 1602
4    35875       37477 1602
5    35875       37477 1602
6    35875       37477 1602
7    35875       37477 1602
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Through further testing on different datasets in the `survival` package, simulated datasets and my own personal dataset (the one I am hoping to use this code on), I have discovered a 'glitch'. In the above version of the code, if a new event `etime[i-1]` falls into one of the periods were we have specified the individual to be immune to having an event - which is exactly the instance the code is designed to create - the event does not get incorporated into the cumulative event counter `cum_infect`. During the next run `etime[i]` the individual will only have [i-1] cumulative events, and the portion of the code that controls whether 30 days should be added to the start time

```
immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect == i), "tstart"] + 30
```

will not identify the individual as having had an event. This means that the forloop will only correctly add a 30 day immunity after an event, until the first instance of an event falling on such an immune period. I produced a rather inelegant fix. But it works.

```
newcgd <- tmerge(data1=cgd0[, 1:13], data2=cgd0, id=id, tstop=futime)
immunecgd <- tmerge(data1=cgd0[, 1:13], data2=cgd0, id=id, tstop=futime)
newcgd$cum_infect_0 <- 0
immunecgd$cum_infect_0 <- 0
event <- matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol = 2)
futime <- matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol = 2)
for(i in 1:7){        
    x <- paste0("etime", i)  #etime1:etime7

    # iteratively add each event
    immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))
    newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, cgd0, id = id, infect = event(cgd0[,x]))

    # select only observations that end in an event and iteratively create
    # cumulative number of events for each individual
    immunecgd <- tmerge(immunecgd, subset(immunecgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))
    newcgd <- tmerge(newcgd, subset(newcgd, infect == 1), id = id, cum_infect = cumtdc(tstop))

    # create new column that will hold cumulative events between loops
    immunecgd[, paste0("cum_infect_", i)] <- immunecgd[, "cum_infect"]
    newcgd[, paste0("cum_infect_", i)] <- newcgd[, "cum_infect"]

    # for each loop add 30 days to the start time if there is atleast one cumulative event
    # and the value of the ith cumulative event is larger than the i-1th cumulative event
    immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect > 0 & immunecgd$cum_infect > immunecgd[, paste0("cum_infect_", i - 1)]), "tstart"] <-
        immunecgd[which(immunecgd$cum_infect > 0 & immunecgd$cum_infect > immunecgd[, paste0("cum_infect_", i - 1)]), "tstart"] + 30
    newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect > 0 & newcgd$cum_infect > newcgd[, paste0("cum_infect_", i - 1)]), "tstart"] <-
        newcgd[which(newcgd$cum_infect > 0 & newcgd$cum_infect > newcgd[, paste0("cum_infect_", i - 1)]), "tstart"]

    # for each loop remove observations were the start time >= stop time
    immunecgd <- immunecgd[which(immunecgd$tstart < immunecgd$tstop),]
    newcgd <- newcgd[which(newcgd$tstart < newcgd$tstop),]

    event[i,] <- c(sum(immunecgd$infect), sum(newcgd$infect))
    futime[i,] <- c(sum(immunecgd$tstop - immunecgd$tstart), sum(newcgd$tstop - newcgd$tstart))
}
immunecgd <- immunecgd[,!grepl("cum_infect_", colnames(immunecgd))]
newcgd <- newcgd[,!grepl("cum_infect_", colnames(newcgd))]

event <- data.frame(event)
colnames(event) <- c("immunity", "no_immunity")
event$diff <- event$no_immunity - event$immunity

futime <- data.frame(futime)
colnames(futime) <- c("immunity", "no_immunity")
futime$diff <- futime$no_immunity - futime$immunity
```

Here we can see the difference in the total number of events

```
  immunity no_immunity diff
1       44          44    0
2       56          61    5
3       62          69    7
4       64          72    8
5       65          74    9
6       66          75    9
7       66          76   10
```

Correctly specifying the forloop has found 2 more instances were an event fell on an immune period.

Comment: I suppose I could add 7 to tstart at every step?

Comment: I suppose you _could_ offer a [MCVE].

Comment: If I could I would have answered my own question. I honestly don't know how to do what I am asking.

Comment: Did you read the citation? It has nothing to do with "HOW to do X" but everything to do with how to ASK: "how to do X" so that someone can answer it with tested code. Might also be useful to read:  "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way" <http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html>

Comment: I will attempt to do as you suggest

Comment: I apparently screwed up the HTML linkage to: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @42- I have provided what I believe to be the correct solution and clarified the questions to the best of my ability. I read the links you provided and I am aware that this does not yet constitute a great question. However, I feel like the situation breaks the form a bit, because I suspect that I have answered my original question. I would appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: So within each subject you what to change any has-event markers to non-events if they are within 30 days of the start of the interval? Can't you then just tabulate the intervals with events to check?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, here's what I see when I try to implement it in code:

```
 with( newcgd, table( tstart-tstop <= 30, infect))
 #-------------
      infect
         0   1
  TRUE 120  68
```

So if I understand your goal correctly, I don't think you are there yet, and I wonder if you messed things up because:

```
> newcgd$infect <- with( newcgd,ifelse(infect, tstart-tstop > 30, 0 ) )
> with( newcgd, table( tstart-tstop <= 30, infect))
      infect
         0
  TRUE 188
```

When I set all the short interval-events to 0, I get no events at all. But maybe I haven't understood the issues?

Comment: I have added some error-testing code above that I think serves a dual purpose of better explaining what I am attempting to do. I look forward to the day when I understand survival analysis to the degree that I can easily explain what I am doing, until then, thank you for taking the time.

Comment: I may have been unclear. One of the criteria I needed to make sure was fullfilled was that `with( newcgd, table( tstop - tstart <= 0, infect))` gives only `FALSE` . Which it seems to do.

Comment: The value is `0` so if you coerce to logical that is what you get, as well as being the "interpretation when acted upon by a logical operator.